# Who sings "Want You Gone" by Jonathan Coulton?

Tags: portal-2

What is the name of the singer who sings the Portal 2 song "Want You Gone" by Jonathan Coulton?

Comment: She also performs the voice of GLaDOS and the turrets. I highly recommend playing portal 1 with commentaries on, to hear how it was her experience making the game (I still haven't listen to the commentaries on portal 2)

Comment: Portal 2 commentaries are few and far between, sadly. :/

Comment: The Final Hours of Portal 2 is more insightful in that regard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Half Life Wikia](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Want_You_Gone), it is Ellen Mclain:

```
It was written by Jonathan Coulton and performed by Ellen McLain.
```

Answer (score 24):

From [lyrics.wikia.com](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Jonathan_Coulton:Want_You_Gone):

> Singer: **Ellen McLain** as the character GLaDOS in the Valve video game Portal 2

More info on [Ellen McLain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_McLain).

Comment: Upvote for being first and for having the relevant information that she's the voice of GLaDOS.